# Java writing and reading bytes to/from a file

Tags: java, save, byte, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

In a program I'm making, i save certain values as bytes to a file, and i want to load that file and read each byte `dis.read();` but each time I do that, the values come out incorrect. Here is my saving code:

```
file2 = new File(newComputer.file1.toString() + "\\saves\\" + name);
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file2 + ".dat");
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
    dos.writeInt(character.pos.x);
    dos.writeInt(character.pos.y);
    dos.writeInt((int)Minecraft.sx);
    dos.writeInt((int)Minecraft.sy);
    dos.writeInt((int)Minecraft.dir);
    dos.flush();
    dos.writeInt(sky.r);
    dos.writeInt(sky.g);
    dos.writeInt(sky.b);
    dos.writeInt(sky.dayFrame);
    dos.writeInt(sky.changeFrame);
    dos.writeInt(sky.time);
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and here is the loading code:

```
file2 = new File(newComputer.file1.toString() + "\\saves\\" + name);
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file2);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        int tmp = 0;
        //first get the character's x position
        tmp = dis.read();
        System.out.println("x: " + tmp);
        character.x = tmp;
        //then get the character's y position
        tmp = dis.read();
        System.out.println("y: " + tmp);
        character.y = tmp;
        //then get the camera's x position
        tmp = dis.read();
        System.out.println("sx: " + tmp);
        Minecraft.sx = tmp;
        //then get the camera's y position
        tmp = dis.read();
        System.out.println("sy: " + tmp);
        Minecraft.sy = tmp;
        //then get the character's facing position
        tmp = dis.read();
        System.out.println("facing: " + tmp);
        Minecraft.dir = tmp;
        //then get the sky's RGB colors
        tmp = dis.read();
        System.out.println("r: " + tmp);
        sky.r = tmp;
        tmp = dis.read();
        System.out.println("g: " + tmp);
        sky.g = tmp;
        tmp = dis.read();
        System.out.println("b: " + tmp);
        sky.b = tmp;
        //render the world
        Minecraft.hasStarted = true;
        Minecraft.played++;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What does `dis.read();` do?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm pretty sure it reads the next byte of the file? But thats just me, I'm not very good when it comes to bytes.

Comment: [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) the javadoc. Yes, it does read the next byte. You're writing an `int` for the `x` position but reading only a `byte`. Do you see how those are not equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using `read()` instead of `readInt()`

Using `read()` return an `int` which lowest 8 bits are a single byte read from the file.
The `readInt()` method however, reads a full 32 bit (4 8-bit bytes) from the file, which is what you're writing to the file.